# Breakpoint will not currently be hit because source code is different in razor code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here's the error message that I'm getting on a breakpoint in my razor code:

> A copy of index.cshtml was found in App_Web_cmi1k1de.dll (Server-side
>   symbols), but the source code is different from the version built into
>   App_Web_cmi1k1de.dll (Server-side symbols).  To allow the breakpoint
>   to be hit when the source is different blah blah blah...

I was getting a very similar error message and I went to the Configuration Manager in my solution and found that one project wasn't set to "debug."  I changed it to debug, cleaned out everything in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\932eeb02\b9cdc481\, and rebuilt my solution.  I see that now in this folder I see a

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\932eeb02\b9cdc481\App_Web_cmi1k1de.dll

together with a

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\932eeb02\b9cdc481\App_Web_cmi1k1de.pdb

These two files have identical timestamps, down the second.  Any idea why I'm getting this error?  It doesn't make any sense that the source code would be different than the compiled .dll.

Comment: if you make a rebuild of the solution before start debuging you won't recieve that message and the breakpoint will eventualy be hited if the code gets there

Comment: When I get this type of issue, it's either a completely unrelated issue, like a compilation error somewhere else or a bad reference or something, or it's just one of those things that goes away on its own after a reboot. I've never found a good answer to this.

Comment: rebuild and delete the content of asp.net temp folder..

Comment: I'm not sure if I made it clear in my original post, but I cleared out the temporary asp.net files I did a rebuild and still get the error.  I did find that if I right clicked on the breakpoint in my razor view and chose allow source code to be different, that I hit the breakpoint and my variables, etc. looked normal.

Comment: please remove all fiels from output path, for ASP MVC it should be `\bin\`, after this, rebuild solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stop debugging, check that the IIS (or IISExpress) process is no longer running - stop it if required, in Visual Studio right-click the solution Clean, then rebuild. Try debugging again.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio on your view file, right click properties, Copy to output directory: **Copy if newer** or **Copy Always**

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me.  Restarting VS did not work either.  Turned out to be related to a recent change I had made to another file.  Even though that complied OK, when I undid the change, the error went away.